# Build always takes forever

Tags: visual-studio-2013, msbuild, tfsbuild

When I queue my builds in VS 2013 using the "Hosted Build Controller"(Visual studio online) my build keeps saying:
![enter image description here][1]
Position In Queue = 1 (Waits in the Queue for more than half an hour)

It is not starting my builds inspite that fact that I have no other builds in queue or or running.

Sometimes it gives me the message saying the connection to the build server was lost.

Not Sure why this is happening because earlier when I initiated my builds using VS 2010, my builds used to start immediately.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I just assumed because I'm using a free account that it can take a few minutes to start running the build. Seems you get what you pay for in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You're dealing with what can be a painful issue.  Have you tried creating another agent?  You can specify which agent to use when queuing the build.  If other agents work and not this once, you may have encountered a bug that requires updates to your current version of TFS.

If new agents consistently fail or don't fail always, then you're dealing with a bigger issue that can be due to performance, cross-geography issues, or with too much latency loading your template.  I believe one thing that can cause issues with this is having too many agents.  I would also try clearing your build caches out.  C:\users[user]\appdata\local\temp  (i.e. BuildAgent/Controller).  Also, definitely make sure your build software matches your TFS version (including the update).  Slight differences there can cause issues.